# Characteristic polynomial $p_{cA}(t)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials

Let's define $p_{A}(t)$ the characteristic polynomial of square matrix $A$ over $R$.

Prove that for every $c \in R$, $c \ne 0$ the characteristic polynomial $p_{A}(t)$ of the matrix $cA$ is $p_{cA}(t) = c^np ({t\over c}) $

Well, I'm not sure how to approach this question, if anyone has any hints/ideas i'll appreciate that.

Comment: What is $\det(tI-cA)$?

Comment: You need to fix your question. The equality $p_{A}(t) = c^np \left({t\over c}\right)$ is wrong on many levels.

Comment: @GitGud I meant $p_{cA}(t) = c^np ({t\over c}) $

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS It's not quite right. What is $p(t)$?

Comment: @GitGud I just got an answer. I just can't understand how he got $t \over c$..

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS My point was that you want to write $p_{\color{red}A}\left(\frac t c\right)$, not $p\left(\frac t c\right)$.

Comment: @GitGud Yup, didn't notice that. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The determinant has the property $\det(cB)=c^n \det(B)$ for scalars $c$ and $n\times n$ matrices $B$. Thus

$$p_{cA}(t)=\det (cA-tI)=c^n \det\left(A-\frac{t}{c}I\right)=c^n p_A\left(\frac{t}{c}\right)$$

Comment: How did you get $t \over c$?

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS If you can't read it from 'left to right', read it from 'right to left'. Just factor in $c^n$ using the property mentioned in the first line.

Comment: @GitGud Got it now. Thanks!!!